# Appending/formatting a string

Tags: python

In C# to format a string I do:

```
string a = String.Format("/blah/blah/{0}_{1}/blah.html", int1, int2)
```

In Python, does it convert integer to string automatically?

How would I do something similar to above in Python.?

Comment: In case Google didn't work, you could also try http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2.6 and above:

```
a = "/blah/blah/{0}_{1}/blah.html".format(int1, int2)
```

In Python 2.7/3.1 and above, you could also do

```
a = "/blah/blah/{}_{}/blah.html".format(int1, int2)
```

See the [docs on String formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#new-string-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "/blah/blah/%s_%s/blah.html" % (int1, int2)
```